# RegExp not matching newlines in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript, ms-office

I'm writing a Word macro with a VBscript `RegExp` that needs to match newlines as part of the pattern. But I can't get any matches on even a pattern with a single `"\n"`, or `"[\n]"`, or `VBNewLine`. Here's the code I'm testing with:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim myRegExp As New RegExp
    With myRegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\n"
    End With

    If myRegExp.Test(ActiveDocument.Content) Then
        MsgBox ("k")
    End If
End Sub
```

In a document where I hold the enter key for a few seconds and run it, this should open a message box, but nothing happens. But if I type anything else and use a pattern that matches it, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the linebreak you get by pressing ENTER is a *carriage return*, a `\r`.

So, you will be able to get the message pop up is to use

```
.Pattern = "\r"
            ^^
```

If you want to match all newline characters, just use the `[\r\n]+` character class (the `+` quantifier will match 1 or more line feed or carriage return symbols).

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try this next time I’m at a computer where I can work on it.